# Draw a curved line from an arc edge

Tags: c++, opengl, curves

Here's the screenshot of what I am doing. Currently, I'm stuck from drawing a curved borders into this rectangle.

[image: naah]

My first solution was: draw a quartered circle behind the rectangle, but if I adjust the opacity of the shape, as you can see, the quartered circle gets shown.

[image: neeh]

I know this is pretty basic for you guys but I'm not really good at math.

I did try to reuse the computed edges of the arc and add the size of border but I got this as a result.

[image: niih]

I also think of *bezier curves* as a replacement but I think it is more efficient to just reuse the computed vertices and add all the missing ones. Also, I don't know how to compute for the curved points of *bezier curves* and finding the right amount of `t` would be very computationally expensive so I don't implement it.

Here's the code how I draw the **inner** quartered circle and I think I can just reuse it.

```
void drawArc(int x, int y,
             int startAngle, int endAngle,
             uint32_t radiusX, uint32_t radiusY,
             int border_x, int border_y,
             const rgb color,
             const rgb bcX, const rgb bcY,
             uint8_t opacity)
{
    if (radiusX <= 0 || radiusY <= 0) return;

    static constexpr float DTR = 3.14159 / 180;

    float cx, cy;
    int step;

    static std::vector<float> verts;
    static std::vector<uint8_t> colors;

    if (startAngle < endAngle)
    {
        step = +1;
        ++ endAngle;
    } else
    {
        step = -1;
        -- endAngle;
    }

    verts.clear();
    colors.clear();

    verts.push_back(x);
    verts.push_back(y);

    colors.push_back(color[R]);
    colors.push_back(color[G]);
    colors.push_back(color[B]);
    colors.push_back(opacity);

    while (startAngle != endAngle)
    {
        cx = cos(DTR * startAngle) * radiusX;
        cy = sin(DTR * startAngle) * radiusY;

        verts.push_back(x + cx);
        verts.push_back(y - cy);

        colors.push_back(color[R]);
        colors.push_back(color[G]);
        colors.push_back(color[B]);
        colors.push_back(opacity);

        startAngle += step;
    }

    drawElements(GL_POLYGON, sizeof(arcIndices) / sizeof(arcIndices[0]), GL_FLOAT,
                 &verts[0], &colors[0], &arcIndices[0]);

    if (border_x != 0 || border_y != 0)
    {
        //remove (x, y)
        verts.erase(verts.begin(), verts.begin() + 2);

//        float px, py;
//
//        px = *(verts.begin() + 0);
//        py = *(verts.begin() + 1);
//
//        glPointSize(5);
//
//        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
//
//        glColor3ub(0,0,255);
//        glVertex2i(px, py);
//
//        px = *(verts.end() - 2);
//        py = *(verts.end() - 1);
//
//        glColor3ub(255,0,0);
//        glVertex2i(px , py);
//        glEnd();

        //attempting to reuse the edges
        //I think the last vertices are opposed
        //that's why I got a crossed out lines??
        for (int i = 0;i <= 90; ++i)
        {
            verts.push_back(verts[i + 0] + border_x);
            verts.push_back(verts[i + 1] + border_y);

            colors.push_back(bcX[R]);
            colors.push_back(bcX[G]);
            colors.push_back(bcX[B]);
            colors.push_back(opacity);
        }

        //91 = steps from 0-90 degree revolution
        //182 = 91 * 2
        unsigned int index[182 + 91 * 2];
        for (int i = 0;i < 182 + 91 * 2; ++i)
            index[i] = i;

        drawElements(GL_LINE_LOOP, verts.size() / 2, GL_FLOAT,
                    &verts[0], &colors[0], &index[0]);
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

Can't I just reuse the pre-calculated (x,y) before?

[image: nooh]

*Sorry for too much use of pictures*

The red dots are pre-calculated (x, y) I'm referring to and just append the next arc base on this.

I'm gonna render many of this kind so I need as efficient as possible(w/o too much use to trigo functions).

**Update:**

And here is the result I got from using `stencil buffer` as what [Andon M. Coleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2423205/andon-m-coleman) suggested:

[image: nuuh]

Btw, as you can see, I am trying to emulate my own UI using OpenGL :D

Comment: Have you considered using the stencil buffer to literally cut out the regions that your grey shape covers? You would have to change the order you draw things a little bit, but you would not have to use nasty line primitives.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I might use it when I apply texture from that rect, but isn't it expensive to do?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman can you give a link how can I do that? I think that's interesting and would do my future necessities when I start to apply texture on it.

Comment: Not much more expensive than depth testing, actually. The two things are ***very much*** related. It is not a perfect solution by far, but you would not have to worry about matching the vertices of the exterior of the rounded square and the interior of the outline shape up. I do not know of any links that would describe how to do this, I would have to write up some pseudo-code to demonstrate... I can do that tomorrow if you are interested.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman For some reason, I want to draw it like what the html's rectangle do, e.g border with sharp edges together with rounded edges, while the inner rect is different from outer rect(border)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Okay, I'm really interested. I will wait for it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expressed an interest in seeing how this could be solved using the stencil buffer yesterday, so I am following up with some basic pseudo-code.

```
glClearStencil (0x0);
glClear        (GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable       (GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glStencilFunc  (GL_ALWAYS, 0x0, 0x0);

// Add 1 to stencil buffer at every location the object to be bordered is visible
glStencilOp    (GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_INCR);

// Draw your grey object

// Only draw the red border where the grey object was never drawn (stencil = 0x0)
glStencilFunc  (GL_EQUAL, 0x0, 0xff);

// Draw your red quarter circles

glDisable     (GL_STENCIL_TEST);
```

Clearing the stencil buffer everytime you draw your outlined object is probably overkill. If you opt to clear the stencil buffer once per-frame instead, you can do some pretty interesting things. For instance, if you drew the outlines as a separate pass after all non-outlined shapes are drawn you could use this stencil buffer setup to outline the ***union*** (instead of including the intersection of objects as part of the drawn outline) of any overlapping objects.. this would allow you to construct more complicated shapes from your simple rounded rectangles.

Of course for this to work, your pixel format must have a stencil buffer. I will have to leave that part up to you, because the process of setting that up is implementation specific.

Comment: If I move to the top the `glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST)` it works but if I follow what you have posted it doesn't. Anyway, it works really great now! but if I try to add texture on it, it won't show up. Maybe I just need to have a pre-calculation of the order of my drawables. Maybe I leave for a moment the `setup for pixel format` you said as long as I don't see any much to worry. Many many thanks to you :D  `stencil buffer` is one of the best thing I discovered in `OpenGL`

Comment: @mr5: Ah, good point. That totally slipped my mind, I made a couple of changes that should work better.

Comment: Also it works even w/o `glStencilFunc  (GL_ALWAYS, 0x0, 0x0);`, why?

Comment: Because you clear the stencil buffer. It re-uses the last stencil function set, which was EQUAL 0x0... this only passes when the stencil buffer is already cleared. It is generally a good idea to use `GL_ALWAYS` when you want to draw something that writes to the stencil buffer unconditionally, that way it would work even if the stencil buffer had not been cleared immediately before drawing.

Answer (score 1):

`GL_POLYGON` is only for *convex* polygons.

Link together the vertices on your inner and outer radii to form quads/triangles:

[image: partial torus]

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cmath>

void Torus2d
    ( 
    float angle,            // starting angle in radians
    float length,           // length of arc in radians, >0
    float radius,           // inner radius, >0
    float width,            // width of torus, >0
    unsigned int samples    // number of circle samples, >=3
    )
{
    if( samples < 3 ) samples = 3;
    const float outer = radius + width;
    glBegin( GL_QUAD_STRIP );
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i <= samples; ++i )
    {
        float a = angle + ( i / (float)samples ) * length;
        glVertex2f( radius * cos( a ), radius * sin( a ) );
        glVertex2f( outer * cos( a ), outer * sin( a ) );
    }
    glEnd();
}

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    double ar = w / h;
    glOrtho( -4 * ar, 4 * ar, -4, 4, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3ub( 255, 0, 0 );
    Torus2d( 0, 1.57079633, 2, 1, 20 );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am actually confused to the parameters that will be passed in `Torus2D`. Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: @mr5: Edited.  `angle` is how far around counter-clockwise to start the torus.  `length` is how long the torus segment should be.  `radius` is the inner torus radius.  `width` is how wide the torus should be.  The greater `samples` is the better the torus will look, at the expense of more geometry.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about those trigonometric functions. In my case, arcs radii are separated i.e rX, rY. How could I modify it to attain this? Couldn't I just get rid out of those trigo again? Can't I just reuse the precalculated x,y before?