# "Layer blending" with OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-es, libgdx

Adobe has this blending effect in some of their products called "Layer" and it basically achieves what is on the left of this image:

[image]

When overlapping two transparent images drawn in the same batch, what I get is shown on the right, I'm trying to go for the result on the left.

I've never been good with the source/destination blending functions and I'm not even sure if they're the solution to this problem, but if they are, what combination would I need to achieve this effect?

For example:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: Have you considered using the stencil or depth buffer to reject the parts of the cross that overlap? I wrote an [answer to a somewhat similar question a while back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508259/draw-a-curved-line-from-an-arc-edge/20532002#20532002)

Comment: Not sure if it's applicable but based on this [link](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glLogicOp.xml), how about considering `glLogicOp(opcode)` with the opcode set to `GL_OR`?

Comment: Depending on your needs, maybe you could draw your sprites to a FrameBuffer with their interiors fully opaque. Then draw the FrameBuffer's color texture to the screen with a lower alpha level. But if you're trying to do this to various sprites having various amounts of alpha, this method might not work, depending on the look you're trying to achieve.